# How to set nodejs to work synchronously?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

```
var job = new cronJob('* * * * * *', function () {
    Draft.find().then(data => {
        var finalData = data;
        finalData.forEach(function(item2) {
            if (item2.scheduledTime === 'now') {
                finalData.forEach(function (item) {
                    var psms = {
                        phoneno: item.senderdata,
                        sender: item.senderName,
                        message: item.message
                    }
                    var obj = psms;
                    var finalpostsms = obj.phoneno.split("\n").map(s => ({ ...obj,
                        phoneno: +s
                    }));
                    Profsms.bulkCreate(finalpostsms).then(function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            console.log("successfully moved in profsms mysql");

                        } else {
                            console.log("failed");
                        }
                    })
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Better you be in drafts..manual input');
            }
            //delete from draft
            if (item2.scheduledTime === 'now') {
                Draft.findOneAndRemove({
                    _id: item2._id
                }, function (err, employee) {
                    if (err)
                        console.log('err');
                    console.log('Successfully deleted from draft');
                });
            } else {
                console.log('You cant delete from drafts hahaha because no sendnow statement');
            }
        });
    });
}, function () {
    console.log('DelCron Job finished.');
}, true, 'Asia/Calcutta');
```

This above code, working as asynchronously.

I want the above code to be work as synchronous, need some answers. I am a newbie for JS development

Is it possible to do with async await? i dont know how to write async await code.

Comment: You're looking for the documentation.

Comment: willy you post answer? to work the above code as synchronous, it will be very useful for me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait for a JavaScript Promise to resolve before resuming function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921127/how-to-wait-for-a-javascript-promise-to-resolve-before-resuming-function)

Comment: async/await doesn't magically turn your code to synchronous one. They still use promises behind the scene.

Comment: What is synchronous and what is asynchronous? What is a Promise? Have you researched? Have you tried like 1 hour before asking here?  I will answer you question, Yes you can do async/wait but you should try more.

Comment: Yes i researched, but not working, i am new to JS, can you post answer?

Answer (score -1):

Your callback should be

```
async function(){
   let data = await Draft.find();
   ...process data;
}
```

Comment: its showing syntax error near  parameter "async function()" can you edit my question code , and post full answer it will be really helpful :)

Comment: @MohamedSameer: You need to run a version of Node that supports `async`.

Comment: @MohamedSameer: We will not write your function for you.  You need to learn how to write code.

Comment: if once i got answer, i can know about this concept, then i can continue learning to write code, this i want to submit tomoro, thats why i am asking to edit my code, will be really helpful for me if you post answer

Answer (score -1):

This is an async await sample code, you can modify based on your need. But first you need to use Node that support async syntax. I believe node 8 LTS is already have async/await feature.

```
function get() {
 // your db code block
 return Promise.resolve(7);
}

async function main() {
  const r = await get();
  console.log(r);
}

main();
```

Comment: what node version do you use ? have you try this sample code and run it in your terminal ?

Comment: yes i have 8.9.1 its working, but my above code doesnot working

Comment: you need to explain more about what's not working. to simplify the check may be you need to test with simple code block

```async function processPromise() {
 const finalData = await Draft.find();
 console.log('db result', finalData);
 // do another process
 console.log('process finished');
}

new CronJob('* * * * * *', processPromise, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```