# Node.JS - Return Promise Gives 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, promise, return, oauth-1.0a

When I try to call this oauth-1.0 API request,

```
const request = require('request');
const OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a');
const crypto = require('crypto');

function main(params) {
    // Dependencies
    // Initialize
    const oauth = OAuth({
        consumer: {
            key: '****',
            secret: '****'
        },
        signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
        hash_function(base_string, key) {
            return crypto.createHmac('sha1', key).update(base_string).digest('base64');
        }
    });
    // Note: The token is optional for some requests
    const token = {
        key: '****',
        secret: '****'
    };

    const request_data = {
        url: 'http://****/rest/V1/products/12345',
        method: 'GET',
        //data: { status: 'Hello Ladies + Gentlemen, a signed OAuth request!' }
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            url: request_data.url,
            method: request_data.method,
            form: request_data.data,
            headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(request_data, token))
        }, function (err, res, body) {
            //console.log(res.body.name);
            if (err){ 
                reject({
                    statusCode: 500,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: {'message': 'Error processing your request' },
                  });    
            } else {
                resolve({
                    body: JSON.parse(body),
                })
            }
        });
    });
};
exports.main = main;
```

it returns

> Promise { < pending > }
>
> undefined

However when I just use console.log(body), it gives the correct result

..................

.................

....

.....

.....

.....

Comment: You have to wait for the promise to resolve in the `.then` callback.

Comment: Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921127/how-to-wait-for-a-javascript-promise-to-resolve-before-resuming-function

Comment: I was following the layout for the IBM Cloud Functions Weather Template, which has almost the exact same layout as mine (except mine is oauth and the weather isn't). I'm just not sure why that one works but mine does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it it works correct and returns Promise.

So if you want to get "data" from promise, you should use [Promise.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Like in this example  from MDN.

```
const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success!');
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // expected output: "Success!"
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't want to use console.log though. And when I do 'return value', it still gives nothing

Comment: Can you post code where you handling that promise?

Comment: I'll just post the whole thing.

Comment: The example I followed was: https://www.writeurl.com/text/vq2dpbckh93ndvo1aieg/0cw63gdn2eg6bpznc48i , and it works perfectly

Comment: I don't see anything that can cause problems here.
But still it's unclear how you handle call of "main" function.

Comment: hmm.. nevermind. Apparently it works on IBM CloudFunctions when I invoke it, just not on my local terminal. Not sure why though.