# How to stop fetch from executing if previous the fetch errored?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have the following code

```
const result = fetch(`link`${id})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let link;
      if (data && data.url) {
        link = data.url.href;
      }

      return fetch(link);
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(() => {
        //do something
    });

  result
    .then(data => {
      let link;
      if (data && data.url1) {
        link = data.url1.href;
      }

      return fetch(link);
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
```

I'm making the call to the `const result = fetch('link')` and `result.then` depends on the result of the `result`.

But for some `ids` the original fetch is returned with error and I'm doing something in catch for that.

The question is how can I stop the next then on `result` so that If it returned with error the extra request won't be made? (because this request only causes an error)

Comment: `.catch(... return false; ...) ... if(!result) return;`

Comment: You can add the `.catch` at end

Comment: @Anuga tried it - result is ```Promise {<pending>}```  event if I ```return false``` from ```catch```

Comment: that's cause your not waiting for the promise to finish before executing `result.`

Comment: @Anuga but how do I wait for it in this case? Make another  ```then``` after ```catch``` and call ```result.then``` there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921127/how-to-wait-for-a-javascript-promise-to-resolve-before-resuming-function

Comment: All the `then` after `catch` will still run if any of the `then` before the `catch` throw an error. This means that you'll have to add the `catch` at the end of it all if you want to stop if any of the `then` throw an error.

Comment: @Anuga I turn my const ```result``` into async function. Wrapped part where I returning fetch inside ```try``` but ```result()``` is still ```pending```. Maybe it is because I need to do something with ```fetch``` inside ```try``` as well

Comment: @Titus I want to stop ```then``` after my ```catch``` throw an error. And I already have this ```catch```

Comment: If you cannot change the `.catch`'s position you can check `data` in the forth `then`'s callback, it will be `undefined` if an error was thrown. You're already doing that but you're still running `fetch(link)` with an `undefined` `link`.

Comment: @Titus yes, but I don't want for ```result.then``` to be called at all if the error was thrown

Comment: Then throw an error from the `catch` callback, eg: `.catch(err => throw err);`

Comment: @Titus it doesn't change anything - because when I use ```result.then``` ```result``` is still not resolved or rejected

Comment: @Allan You need to make `result` a promise that will in the future be rejected, so that the `then` callback will no run. You cannot really avoid calling `.then()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Only attach a `.catch` handler, if you can handle the error at that point and if you can *continue the regular control flow*. In your case you obviously can't, so don't try to! Remove that `.catch()`add it somewhere down the chain, were it can handle the error.

```
 const result = fetch(`url`).then(/*...*).then(/*...*/);

 const result2 = result.then(/*...*/);

 // Somewhere were result gets used, i.e. when adding it to the UI:
 result.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```