# Are handlers in a promise is executed first (asynchronously executes code)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, handler

I read it in an article that the code below the handlers in a promise is executed first (asynchronously executes code)

```
let promise = Promise.resolve();
promise.then(() => alert("promise done!"));
alert("code finished"); // this alert shows first
```

The above code alerts "code finished" first. To tackle this below is the resolution they have provided

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => alert("promise done!"))
  .then(() => alert("code finished"));
```

My question is in real-time issues, we may have 1000 lines of code below these handlers. We can't handle all within then handler. How to synchronously handle this

Comment: use promise.all() it executes when all the promises are resolved!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait for a JavaScript Promise to resolve before resuming function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921127/how-to-wait-for-a-javascript-promise-to-resolve-before-resuming-function)

Comment: "*We may have 1000 lines of code below these handlers. We can't handle all within then handler.*" - actually yes, you would put everything that needs to run after the promise fulfills inside the handler. Or wrap it in a function and call that from the handler, at least.

Comment: @Bergi What ? if I have 100000 lines, we put everything inside a function to make this work synchronously? So, we literally need to write our whole program keeping promise in mind irrespective of its size?

Comment: Ha, welcome to the world of asynchronous coding @AjithKumar.

Comment: @vinayakshahdeo Can you solve the above problem with promise.all() please?

Comment: @AjithKumar You cannot make it work synchronously anyway. All you can do is make it execute sequentially. And btw, if you have 100000 lines of code that are not already factored into reusable functions, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Bergi Ya.Fine.Sequentially. Why do you think I won't reuse my functions. I have 100000 lines of code return in the best way possible. Now, I am adding a promise to alert something before this code. If I have an alert in my 5th line let us say. What would execute first?

Comment: @Bergi Maybe I am ignorant of this. I just need some clarity.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 :)

Comment: Ajith the promise.all function can only be used with an array. I can do it but it is better to use then for single promise. If you have something like [Promise<pending>, Promise<pending>, Promise<pending>, Promise<pending>] then promise.all is really helpful

Comment: @AjithKumar None of the 100000 lines of function declarations need to go inside the promise handler. Only the code that actually calls them.

Answer (score 0):

Read about `async/await`. It is a way of writing asynchronous code in a synchronous way.

Comment: But how to do it with promises? Then, is it a drawback?

Comment: `async`/`await` is still using promises.

Comment: ASYNC/AWAIT implicitly returns a Promise