# Weird behavior in if statement in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have a simple if statement, which I don't understand !

```
var  internetConnection ="0"
// Checking the internet connection at the start 
  require('dns').resolve('www.google.com', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        internetConnection="1"
         console.log("Internet connection  NO",internetConnection)
    } else {
        internetConnection="0"
        console.log("Internet connection  yes ",internetConnection)
  } 
  });
  console.log("Internet connection  test",internetConnection)
```

here is the output:

```
Internet connection  test 0
Internet connection  NO 1
```

does anybody understand why the correct value isn't been set? I've expected :

```
Internet connection  test 1
```

thanks in advance for any hint!

Comment: The dns promise api is async.  Your test log runs and outputs a 0 before the other code can reassign the variable to 1
https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_promises_api

Comment: @Nick  thanks for your reply, is there a word around for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are new to Nodejs, Most of the Nodejs API is async so you are getting that behavior.

```
console.log("Internet connection  test",internetConnection)
```

the above statement will be executed even before DNS query resolve. you can try below code snippet

```
  var {promisify} = require('util');
  var  internetConnection ="0"
  const dns =  require('dns');
  const resolve= promisify(dns.resolve);
  async function testConnection() { 
  try {
        let res= await resolve('www.google.com')
         console.log(res);
         internetConnection="1"
         console.log("Internet connection  yes ",internetConnection)
         return 1;
     }

     catch (err) {
       internetConnection="0"
       console.log("Internet connection NO ",internetConnection)
       return 0
     }
    }


    testConnection().then(function(result){
    console.log("Internet connection  test",result)
  })
```

Or simply put the `console.log("Internet connection  test", internetConnect))`
  statment inside callback function

```
var internetConnection = "0"
// Checking the internet connection at the start 
require('dns').resolve('www.google.com', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    internetConnection = "1"
    console.log("Internet connection  NO", internetConnection)
  } else {
    internetConnection = "0"
    console.log("Internet connection  yes ", internetConnection)
  }
   console.log("Internet connection  test", internetConnect))
});
```

check this out for demo:https://repl.it/@sandeepp2016/BeigeCriticalKey

Comment: 1. thanks a lot for your answer. It does work as a stand alone app, but when I try to integrate it in the bigger app I get the same behaviour !

Comment: Again it could be because of async execution of a program. You will have to think of control flow. Try to learn more about `promises` and `async-await` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The `resolve` is an `async` method . When you call `resolve` method it will register a callback in the callback queue and wait for the `resolve method` to complete, once the function is completed it will trigger The callback function.

The `Node` will not wait for the callback function, and execute the next statements.

To get the logs statement is sequence and the updated value of the `internetConnection` variable. include the last console statement inside the callback.

**Example.**

```
var internetConnection = "0"
// Checking the internet connection at the start 
require('dns').resolve('www.google.com', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    internetConnection = "1"
    console.log("Internet connection  NO", internetConnection)
  } else {
    internetConnection = "0"
    console.log("Internet connection  yes ", internetConnection)
  }
  console.log("Internet connection  test", internetConnect
});
```

Or you could wrap it in a promise object.

```
const dns = require('dns');

function connectionTest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dns.resolve('www.google.com1', function (err) {
      if (err) {
        let connectionStatus = 1;
        console.log("Internet connection  NO", connectionStatus)
        reject(connectionStatus);
      } else {
        let connectionStatus = 0;
        console.log("Internet connection  yes ", connectionStatus)
        resolve(connectionStatus);
      }
    });
  });
}

(async function() {
  try {
    internetConnection = await connection();
    console.log("Internet connection  test", internetConnection);
  } catch (error) {
    internetConnection = error
    console.log("Internet connection  test", internetConnection);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in javascript, but to me it looks like you are resolving a promise when checking the internet connection. As such, the log statement in the last line could be executed before the promise gets resolved. In that case the variable still has its initial value.

Comment: HI Rob, thanks for your answer, is there a solution for it ?

Comment: You can execute the log statement within a „then“ statement you append to the async resolve call. This would get executed after the promise is resolved.

Comment: well the problem is that I need this value for the rest of the application , and I need the correct value

Comment: You will have to `await` the resolution of the promise. Maybe this answer can shed some light into how to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921127/how-to-wait-for-a-javascript-promise-to-resolve-before-resuming-function

Answer (score 0):

It's because this block of your code is asynchronous:

```
...
require('dns').resolve('www.google.com', function(err) {
   //handle callback
});
...
```

Node.js won't wait for it to process, so it continues and run the other line of your code until your promise resolved.